# How to find out which process keeps tunnel interface(tun) up?

Tags: linux, text-processing, network-interface

If I create a `tun` interface with `ip tuntap add mode tun` command and force it administratively up with `ip link set dev tun1 up` command, then the interface itself is always "physically" down:

```
root@A58:~# ip link show dev tun1
46: tun1: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
    link/none 
root@A58:~#
```

This makes sense as there are no applications connected to this interface. However, I also have `tun0` in my system which is "physically" up:

```
root@A58:~# ip link show dev tun0
45: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 100
    link/none 
root@A58:~#
```

Is there a way to find out which process is connected to this `tun0` interface? I had no luck with `ps -ef | grep tun0` or `lsof | grep tun0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux kernel exposes this info now in `/proc/$PID/fdinfo/$FD`. For example:

```bsh
# grep ^iff: /proc/*/fdinfo/*
/proc/31219/fdinfo/5:iff:       tun0
/proc/31235/fdinfo/5:iff:       tun1
/proc/31252/fdinfo/5:iff:       tun2
/proc/31267/fdinfo/5:iff:       tun3
```

Tested with Debian 5.8.10.

Comment: Strangely, for me (on Mint based upon Ubuntu 18.04) this didn't work but should have.  If instead of `grep ^iff: /proc/*/fdinfo/*` (which for me returns nothing) I do `grep -R ^iff: /proc/*/fdinfo` it gives similar output to the above!

Actually, I take that back!  It does work but only when logged in as root.  If I run the command via `sudo` it doesn't work, presumably because my user is not allowed to see what's below `/proc/*/fdinfo`.  I considered deleting my comment but actually, I can't be the only one who will make that mistake! :-)

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't looks like the kernel exposes this information. Therefore, short of kernel debugging, I don't think you can know this. The best you can do is list all processes that have `tun` or `tap` devices open like this:

```
lsof /dev/net/tun
```

So that will narrow it down, but in the case where there are multiple active `tun` interfaces on the system, it doesn't tell you which process is managing which tunnel.

When a process wants to create a `tun` interface, it opens `/dev/net/tun` no matter which `tun` interface it intends to use. Then, it either lets the kernel dynamically assign a new `tun` interface name (like `tun0`, `tun1`, `tun2` etc...) or it sets a chosen name. This is done with an `ioctl` call with code `TUNSETIFF`. So unless you get to trace that `ioctl` call, there isn't really a way to tell what name got assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the /proc filesystem you can use this sequence of commands:

```
find /proc/ -name tun0 | cut -d\/ -f3 | uniq | xargs -IPID lsof -p PID
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything useful at all for me. The `find` finds a whole bunch of files under `/proc/sys/net` and even more under `/proc/<every single process id>/net/dev_snmp6`, none of which are useful to pipe info `lsof`. As for `lsof`, I can see that processes using `tun` devices hold open `/dev/net/tun` and that tells you that the process is sitting behind a `tun`/`tap` interface but it doesn't tell you *which one*.

Comment: I don't understand. The <every single process_id> is what you're attempting to pipe to lsof -using the -P option which takes a pid.

Using this method worked on my system. What version of lsof? I'm using 4.87

Comment: Why do you want to find every valid process ID on the system (or more correctly, every process ID that exists in the same network namespace as the `tun` interface... but that usually means every process on the system) and pipe them all into `lsof`? It doesn't give you any information about which process is controlling the tun interface.